# Z-Index of series in ShieldUI charts

Tags: asp.net, z-index, shieldui

I want to know how change Z-index of series in charts. Indeed, I want my range area series to be always in the background.

Thanks

Comment: Will you mind to post what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support contacted me to let me know that their developers have completed the feature identified as missing.

In this exemple, we can see that the 2nd data series should be on top of the other: http://demos.shieldui.com/mvc/splinearea-chart/multi-axis

It will be avaible after the next Shield UI realease is out.

Comment: The latest release is out now.

Answer (score 1):

I finally modified the order of the series to make my rangearea first.

Thanks

Comment: That will work. Additionally, in JavaScript you can add a zIndex property to a specific item in your dataSeries list. However, it seems this is not implemented for Shield UI for ASP.NET MVC yet...

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the zIndex property for the series settings?

Comment: Hi,
I don't find the property zIndex in the series settings.